# multiple ids aria-labelledby Internet Exporer 11 issue

Tags: internet-explorer, accessibility, wai-aria

We are checking the accessibility of the following code sample in various browsers like IE 11, Mozilla Fire Fox etc using JAWS

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <body>
    <form>

      <label id="group1" tabIndex="-1">Sandwich Condiments</label>
      <input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="label1 group1">
      <label id="label1">Lettuce</label>
      </input>

      <input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="label2 group1">
      <label id="label2">Tomato</label>
      </input>

      <input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="label3 group1">
      <label id="label3">Mustard</label>
      </input>

      <input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="label4 group1">
      <label id="label4">Sprouts</label>
      </input>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

In Mozilla FireFox , when we tab to a check box  for ex- Lettuce , it is read as **Lettuce Sandwich Condiments checkbox  checked/ unchecked**

where as in Internet Explorer, it is read as **Lettuce checkbox  checked/ unchecked** . The Sandwich Condiments is omitted, so it is becoming difficult to provide a context to users.

Any idea how this can be resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With radio buttons and checkboxes, you're over complicating this by using `aria-labelledby`.

The best pattern for screen reader support is to use a `<fieldset>` around the inputs, with a `<legend>`.

In your case this would look like:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Sandwich Condiments</legend>

    <input type="checkbox">
            <label id="label1">Lettuce</label>
    </input>

    <input type="checkbox">
            <label id="label2">Tomato</label>
    </input>

    <input type="checkbox">
            <label id="label3">Mustard</label>
    </input>

    <input type="checkbox">
            <label id="label4">Sprouts</label>
    </input>
</fieldset>
```

Much cleaner, and you can hide the border of the fieldset easily with CSS if that puts you off.

Further explanation: https://accessibility.blog.gov.uk/2016/07/22/using-the-fieldset-and-legend-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I am using JAWS17 with IE11 and I see that **Lettuce Sandwich Condiments checkbox checked/ unchecked** is read fine. The issue is probably with due to an older version JAWS (or browser) being used.